# When is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = 0$?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ be given by:
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^t \sin \frac{1}{x^2} & \text{if } x\ne0 \\
0 &\text{if } x=0 \ 
\end{cases}.
$$
For what values of $t\in\mathbb R$ is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = 0$?

I tried caclulate the right derivative at $x = 0$, and it's $0$, but I'm having troubles calculating the left derivative.

Help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the typical exercise that you solve by looking directly at
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} x^{t-1} \sin (x^{-2}).
$$
It is easy to find a sufficient condition for the existence of this limit (what?). Then you should check that your condition is also necessary.

**Edit:** the function is defined correctly only if $x>0$, otherwise $x^t$ may make no sense at all for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Actually $f$ is not even defined on a whole left neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: I thought the condition is the left limit equals the right limit but I can't calculate the left..

Comment: Why? What are your difficulties?

Comment: you mean x > 0, not t?

Comment: what's the problem with t < 0? x^-2 is ok, when x=0, f(x)=0..

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: The problem with $t = -0.5 < 0$ is that, when $x < 0$, $x^t$ yields an invalid value.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura $x^y$ cannot be suitably defined when $x<0$, even if $y>0$.